# How to determine negotiated TLS version, and Cipher using PHP on server side

Tags: php, ssl

is there a way to determine negotiated TLS protocol version, and cipher using PHP.

Currently, I can use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] or $_SERVER[HTTPS]
```

to detect if my page is being accessed over HTTPS, however I need to find negotiated cipher, key exchange method, and TLS version. I would also like to get list of ciphers initially presented by the client in SSL handshake.

Basically I want to build something like Qualys TLS client test  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

Comment: The SAPI you are using would have to provide this information to you. I don't think there is any SAPI that does so -- certainly none of the commonly used ones. So you are likely out of luck.

Comment: I know this is old but.. I am not sure if you do own your entire system so that you can setup the HTTP server by your own. If it is the case, then you might consider checking this nginx module which provides low-level TLS negotiation API
https://github.com/fooinha/nginx-ssl-ja3